Newtons formula Ray optics
So recently I learnt about Newton's formula and everything about image formation by mirrors. So the newton's formula goes like this,
X° =object distance from focal plane (perpendicular)
X`= image distance from focal plane.
So if you multiple both X° and X then using mirror formula we get X°×X`= square of focal length.

So if you have read my page I ended up with a question of why does image and object are always on the same side of focal plane ??
I know about practical proof and all, but still, how can we explain it with Newton's formula?

Please make the image upright. And use MathJax for formulae.

To have a real image and a real object both the object distance and the image distance must be greater than the focal length. The object and image are in the same position when the distances are twice the focal length. Then as one moves towards the focal plane the other moves away from the focal plane, both being on the same side as the focal plane.

@VincentThacker First task completed!
